# RSET vs EHLO smtp client

Tags: smtp

In [**sec. 4.1.1.5**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.5) of RFC5321 said:

> Since EHLO implies some additional processing and response by the
> server, RSET will normally be more efficient than reissuing that
> command, even though the formal semantics are the same.

What is the "some additional processing" except the `EHLO` response contain keywords (and associated parameters if required) for all commands not listed as "required" in Section 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The `EHLO` command processing itself may incur any site defined checks on the name provided like anti spam checks or what ever (many MTA's checks that the name is a legal `FQDN`, for example) while `RSET` command just resets the state machine and frees any possibly allocated resources such as `MAIL FROM` address or `RCPT TO` addresses list.